# How do I get information about geobjects from a geoserver layer using the GetFeatureInfo?

Tags: geoserver, wms

In **GeoServer** I successfully created **WMS layer** based on **PostgreSQL** table which has such structure:

```
| COLUMN NAME | DATA TYPE |
|-------------|-----------|
| id          | numeric   |
| geom        | geometry  |
| city        | varchar   |
| info        | jsonb     |
```

Each record in that table is unique and it's one polygon. In other words, this layer has a lot of polygons. With `GetMap` WMS request I put this layer to the map of the web application. When the user clicks to one of these polygons I want to know information about it. For example information from `city` and `info` columns. As far as I understand I have to make a [GetFeatureInfo](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) WMS request for this task, right? I tried such `GET` request to `GeoServer`, but it returns me the empty result. What I did wrong?

**GET REQUEST**:

```
http://{{domain_name}}/geoserver/{{namespace_name}}/wms?&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&
LAYERS={{layer_name}}&
SRS=EPSG%3A4326&
CRS=CRS%3A84&
FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&
BBOX=51.08443921044546%2C71.3090464064941%2C51.18218384993084%2C71.55709709619134&
WIDTH=1366&
HEIGHT=905&
QUERY_LAYERS={{layer_name}}&
INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&
FEATURE_COUNT=50&
I=498&
J=391&
EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_xml&
STYLES=squaremesh_style
```

**RESULT**:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [],
    "totalFeatures": "unknown",
    "numberReturned": 0,
    "timeStamp": "2019-12-24T17:59:23.429Z",
    "crs": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there is nothing visible at pixel (669, 491) - did you try other points?

However, there are a [number of issues with your request](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms) (though I think GeoServer takes a lenient view of some of them):

1. For version 1.3.0 of WMS you should use `I` and `J` for the query point.
2. Your SRS should be EPSG:4326.
3. You are missing a STYLES parameter

Finally, if all else fails don't be afraid to check the log file to see if an error is being logged.

Comment: I tried to change `x/y` properties to `1` and `width/height` properties to `2`. In that case, after click to the specific polygon, I have an array of all polygons which are available in the layer. In any other values of `x/y` properties, `GeoServer` returns me the empty result. I also tried to change `x/y` to `i/j` and I added `STYLES` parameter as you recommended. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: GetFeatureInfo works by querying the **pixel** of your map image - so in a 2x2 image all polygons will match. Try looking with a graphics program to see what is at 669, 491

Comment: What kind of graphics program for this task you can recommend?

Comment: Anything that can open the image and show you the position of the mouse

Comment: It's so strange behavior. I removed the `CRS` parameter. After that my `GetFeatureInfo` query returns information about selected polygon. With this parameter, it always returns an empty array. Do you have any ideas about it? Also, I notice that in some zoom it doesn't work perfectly.

Comment: Did you check the specification I linked to, or check the log for errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the opportunity to get the GeoServer logs. I will study the specification in more detail. I noticed that there is a `wms` layer shift on the map.  I haven't found the reason yet.